# Addon - Forget Password Email Hook

Tags: hook, forgot-password

Is there an add-on that can provide a hook to change the forget password email?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a hook to change the contents of the email for forgotten passwords.

Just go to Design -> Message Pages -> Email Notifications